# CRM2011 - Plugin to fire on SetState for contract entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a plugin that should fire on SetState message on the contract entity but it isn´t.
If I register it for the message SetStateDynamicEntity instead it fires and works ok.

Why is this??? Reading the SDK I understood SetStateDynamic is replaced by SetState on CRM2011.
Can someone please help me understand...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a blog post that sounds similar to your problem:

http://dmcrm.blogspot.com/2008/05/plugins-triggered-off-setstate-message.html

Since contract is a system entity, you might need to look for a special message like he describes the in the post above.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's similar... but my problem is with the 2011 version. I know that on Crm4 you must register the plugin on both messages (SetState and SetStateDynamic). I just thougt that with crm 2011 SetState was the only one needed (since DynamicEntity does not exist anymore...)

Comment: Dynamic Entities still exist, they are just called "Entity" instead of "DynamicEntity."